# Function scope & incrementing parameters

Tags: c, function, scope

A sample problem asks us to consider the code below and predict what will be printed out by the function `funct_1`:

```
void func_1(int i, int j) {
    printf("i is %d, j is %d\n", i, j);
}
/*   ...   */
/* somewhere in the code, a call to func_1 */
int i = 30;
func_1(i, i++);
/*   ...   */
```

I thought that when parameters are passed in this form where they are incremented, it is impossible to predict when the compiler would increment i. The solution, however, is:

```
The values in the argument are passed as an attack to the function, hence 'j' receives 
a value '30' and then i receives the incremented value which is '31'.

Output: i is 31, j is 30
```

Could someone please explain what an attack to a function is and how this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is wrong in general.  You are correct; the behaviour of the code is undefined.  On some compilers, the answer might be 30 and 31; on others, it might be 30 and 30; on others, it might be 31 and 31; and others might simply erase all the files on your hard drive (because undefined behaviour is undefined).  Fortunately, the radical, remove-all-traces-of-the-trouble behaviour is relatively unlikely in a compiler.

For some specific compiler on some specific platform, the solution is probably correct.

---

Actually, I think that it is not possible to get 31 for `j` in `func_1()` - but an operation sequence that produces 30 and 30 is easily imaginable: the value of `i` is pushed twice, then I is incremented, then the function is called.

Comment: Now I'm thoroughly confused. The question doesn't state that we are to assume a certain platform, but specifically states that `i is 31` and `j is 30`. =/

Comment: @raphnguyen: I'm sorry you are confused.  The trouble is that the question is not very good - asking as it does about undefined behaviour.  And the answer isn't very good - stating as gospel what is at most the behaviour exhibited by one specific (but as yet unstated) compiler.  Unfortunately, GCC 4.6.0 on MacOS X 10.6.7 set fussy gives "warning: operation on ‘i’ may be undefined" and the result "i is 31, j is 30", so I have not proved my point.

Comment: @raphnguyen: I've checked on Solaris 10 (SPARC); that produces 31/30.  I've check on HP-UX 11.23; that produces 30/30.  I checked on AIX 6.1; that produces 30/30.

Comment: Ah, shucks. I'll have to ask for clarification from my professor before tomorrow's exam then. Thanks so much for trying to clear up the confusion!

Answer (score 3):

It is not impossible to predict; compilers work in a deterministic manner, even in the grey areas poorly covered or not covered by the specs. With *this* specific compiler arguments are pushed right to left, and the post-increment occurs shortly after the right parameter has been pushed.

Comment: Thanks, but why is it right to left versus left to right? When I read the code, it seems to me that `i = 30` and after incremnting `i`, `j = 31`.